# What does the thread_local mean in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-local, thread-local-storage

I am confused with the description of `thread_local` in C++11. My understanding is, each thread has unique copy of local variables in a function. The global/static variables can be accessed by all the threads (possibly synchronized access using locks). And the `thread_local` variables are visible to all the threads but can only modified by the thread for which they are defined? Is it correct?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794382/are-c11-thread-local-variables-automatically-static

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Thread-local storage duration is a term used to refer to data that is *seemingly* global or static storage duration (from the viewpoint of the functions using it) but, in actual fact, there is one copy per *thread.*

It adds to the current options:

- automatic (exists during a block or function);
- static (exists for the program duration); and
- dynamic (exists on the heap between allocation and deallocation).

Something that is thread-local is brought into existence at thread creation time and disposed of when the thread finishes.

---

For example, think of a random number generator where the seed must be maintained on a per-thread basis. Using a thread-local seed means that each thread gets its own random number sequence, independent of all other threads.

If your seed was a local variable within the random function, it would be initialised every time you called it, giving you the same number each time. If it was a global, threads would interfere with each other's sequences.

---

Another example is something like `strtok` where the tokenisation state is stored on a thread-specific basis. That way, a single thread can be sure that other threads won't screw up its tokenisation efforts, while still being able to maintain state over multiple calls to `strtok` - this basically renders `strtok_r` (the thread-safe version) redundant.

---

Yet *another* example would be something like `errno`. You don't want separate threads modifying `errno` after one of your calls fails, but before you've had a chance to check the result.

---

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) has a reasonable description of the different storage duration specifiers.

Comment: Using thread local doesn't solve the problems with `strtok`.  `strtok` is broken even in a single threaded environment.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase that. It doesn't introduce any _new_ problems with strtok :-)

Comment: Actually, the `r` stands for "re-entrant", which has nothing to do with thread safety. It's true that you can make some things work thread-safely with thread-local storage, but you can't make them re-entrant.

Comment: In a single-threaded environment, functions need to be re-entrant only if they are part of a cycle in the call graph. A leaf function (one that doesn't call other functions) is by definition not part of a cycle, and there is no good reason why `strtok` should call other functions.

Comment: this would mess it up:
    `while (something) { char *next = strtok(whatever); someFunction(next); // someFunction calls strtok }`

Comment: @MSalters: You get problems if you (try to) intertwine two `strtok` sequences in one thread; say, if you're processing two strings at the same time. That's where the reentrant variants come in handy (plus it's cleaner --- no globals are accessed).

Comment: Does a ```thread_local object``` calls its deallocator at the end of the thread ?

Comment: +1 Great example for `strtok`. I checked glibc from the tip, the implementation of `strtok` is by two lines and calls `strtok_r`.

Comment: Some code samples would be nice

Answer (score 188):

When you declare a variable `thread_local` then each thread has its own copy. When you refer to it by name, then the copy associated with the current thread is used. e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

thread_local int i = 0;

void setNewVal(int newval)
{
    i = newval;
}

void print()
{
    std::cout << i;
}

void thread_func(int id)
{
    setNewVal(id);
    ++i;
    print();
}

int main()
{
    i = 9;

    std::thread t1(thread_func, 1);
    std::thread t2(thread_func, 2);
    std::thread t3(thread_func, 3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

This code will output "2349", "3249", "4239", "4329", "2439" or "3429", but never anything else. Each thread has its own copy of `i`, which is assigned to, incremented and then printed. The thread running `main` also has its own copy, which is assigned to at the beginning and then left unchanged. These copies are entirely independent, and each has a different address.

It is only the **name** that is special in that respect --- if you take the address of a `thread_local` variable then you just have a normal pointer to a normal object, which you can freely pass between threads. e.g.

```
thread_local int i = 0;

void thread_func(int *ptr)
{
    *ptr = 42;
}

int main()
{
    i = 9;
    std::thread t(thread_func, &i);
    t.join();
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Since the address of `i` is passed to the thread function, then the copy of `i` belonging to the main thread can be assigned to even though it is `thread_local`. This program will thus output "42". If you do this, then you need to take care that `*p` is not accessed after the thread it belongs to has exited, otherwise you get a dangling pointer and undefined behavior just like any other case where the pointed-to object is destroyed.

`thread_local` variables are initialized "before first use", so if they are never touched by a given thread then they are not necessarily ever initialized. This is to allow compilers to avoid constructing every `thread_local` variable in the program for a thread that is entirely self-contained and doesn't touch any of them. e.g.

```
struct my_class
{
    my_class() { std::cout << "hello"; }
    ~my_class() { std::cout << "goodbye"; }
};

void f()
{
    thread_local my_class unused;
}

void do_nothing() { }

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(do_nothing);
    t1.join();
}
```

In this program there are 2 threads: the main thread and the manually-created thread. Neither thread calls `f`, so the `thread_local` object is never used. It is therefore unspecified whether the compiler will construct 0, 1 or 2 instances of `my_class`, and the output may be "", "hellohellogoodbyegoodbye" or "hellogoodbye".

Comment: I think it is important to note that the thread-local copy of the variable is a newly initialized copy of variable. That is, if you add a `g()` call to the beginning of `threadFunc`, then the output will be `0304029` or some other permutation of the pairs `02`, `03`, and `04`. That is, even though 9 is assigned to `i` before the threads are created, the threads get a freshly constructed copy of `i` where `i=0`. If `i` is assigned with `thread_local int i = random_integer()`, then each thread gets a new random integer.

Comment: Not exactly a permutation of `02`, `03`, `04`, there may be other sequences like `020043`

Comment: Interesting tidbit I just found: GCC supports using the address of a thread_local variable as template argument, but other compilers do not (as of this writing; tried clang, vstudio). I'm not sure what the standard has to say about that, or if this is a unspecified area.

Answer (score 31):

Thread-local storage is in every aspect like static (= global) storage, only that each thread has a separate copy of the object. The object's life time starts either at thread start (for global variables) or at first initialization (for block-local statics), and ends when the thread ends (i.e. when `join()` is called).

Consequently, only variables that could also be declared `static` may be declared as `thread_local`, i.e. global variables (more precisely: variables "at namespace scope"), static class members, and block-static variables (in which case `static` is implied).

As an example, suppose you have a thread pool and want to know how well your work load was being balanced:

```
thread_local Counter c;

void do_work()
{
    c.increment();
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(do_work);   // your thread-pool would go here
    t.join();
}
```

This would print thread usage statistics, e.g. with an implementation like this:

```
struct Counter
{
     unsigned int c = 0;
     void increment() { ++c; }
     ~Counter()
     {
         std::cout << "Thread #" << std::this_thread::id() << " was called "
                   << c << " times" << std::endl;
     }
};
```

Comment: Did you not mean `std::this_thread::get_id()` in your `std::cout`?