# Is there an equivalent of Java 'volatile' in C++?

Tags: java, c++, windows, multithreading

In Java, sometimes when accessing the same variable from different threads, each thread will create its own copy of the variable, and so if I set the value of the variable in one thread to `10` and then I tried to read the value of this variable from another thread, I will not get `10` (because the second thread is reading from another copy of the variable!).

To fix this problem in Java, all I had to do is to use the keyword volatile, for example:

```
volatile int i = 123;
```

Does this problem also exists in C++? If so, how can I fix it?

**Note:** I am using Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: the simplest approach is std::atomic.

Comment: `std::atomic` is not available in VC2010. `boost::atomic` is an option.

Comment: Please read what `volatile` is (in Java). It seems you´re overestimating what it can do. And no, without `volatile` it is not "one copy per thread".

Comment: @deviantfan I think the OP is just talking about the compiler caching a value in register, which is technically "creating a copy'. Not the best way of thinking about it.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: @DJClayworth Maybe that´s what the OP is thinking, maybe not, that´s why I wrote it in the first place (that he should read something more about it)

Comment: Well, the threadcopy problem seems solved, but still: Read about volatile in Java. It´s *not* a perfect solution for thread safety in any and every situation. And C++ volatile is even less.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the same problem exists in C++. But since C already introduce the keyword `volatile` with a different meaning (not related to threads), and C++ used they keyword in the same way, you can't use `volatile` in C++ like you can in Java.

Instead, you're probably better off using `std::atomic<T>` (or boost::). It's not always the most efficient alternative, but it's simple. If this turns out to be a bottleneck, you can relax the `std::memory_order` used by `std::atomic`.

Having said that about standard C++, MSVC++ as an extension does guarantee that multiple threads can access a shared `volatile` variable. IIRC, all threads will *eventually* see the same value, and no threads will travel back in time. (That is to say, if 0 and 1 are written to a variable sequentially, no thread will ever see the sequence 1,0)

Comment: Isn't `std::atomic` only available in C++11?

Comment: @paul: Yes, but that's logical because C++03 didn't even have threads.

Comment: So how can I fix this problem if I'm using Visual C++ 2010, does Windows API provide a solution?

Comment: @paul: Use boost - the C++11 solution was directly derived from Boost. Once you upgrade to an up-to-date version of MSVC, you can probably replace `using boost::atomic` with `using std::atomic`.

Comment: What if I am only using C and Windows API threads, do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @paul: Slap a `CriticalSection` on the variable. You can't expect the most primitive API to offer all the niceties of more advanced API's.

Comment: You mean I should wrap the code that accesses (read/write) the variable with a critical section?

Comment: @paul: if you are using Microsoft C and Windows API threads, and dealing with 32-bit integers, `volatile` is probably all you need.  Introducing a critical section would be overkill.

Comment: ... on the other hand, that depends on how you're using the variable.  If you don't understand how multiprocessor CPUs affect thread safety, you may be better off playing it safe and using critical sections after all.

Comment: @Harry Johnston So you mean that the value of a 32-bit integer could be cached by each thread, but a `struct` for example will not?

Comment: With a `struct` the problem is that you may see changes for some members before you see changes for others.  Similarly, if you print a string while another thread is changing it you might wind up printing some characters from one string and some characters from another.  The platforms that Windows runs on all guarantee that when you read a properly aligned 32-bit integer you won't get a mixture of two different values.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Should I use `volatile` for each member of a `struct`, or can I just use `volatile` with the entire `struct` when declaring an instance of it (Note that I am talking about `volatile` in MSVC++)?

Comment: You can't use `volatile` to solve that problem.  You need a critical section or similar locking mechanism.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Isn't a critical section used to force a thread to execute a piece code only when the other thread has finished executing it? What I was talking about is not allowing each thread to make its own "copy" of the variable.

Comment: @paul: A critical section usually protects a shared variable. A single critical section may therefore be locked by multiple functions.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, this is what I thought. But a critical section does not prevent each thread from creating its own "copy" of the shared variable, this is the job of `volatile` (at least in MSVC++), correct?

Comment: @paul: Just to make it explicit: what you see is NOT each thread having its own copy. What you see is stale caches, missing register reloads and other Undefined Behavior. To give each thread its own copy, you need [`thread_local`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983875/what-does-the-thread-local-mean-in-c11).

Comment: @MSalters Yes, so there is only one copy of the variable in memory, but each CPU can cache the value of the variable in its cache and access the cache from now own (hence the illusion of a separate copy).

Comment: @paul: Indeed, and a CriticalSection will force out stale cache values.

Comment: [Under Visual Studio 2005 and later](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686355%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `volatile` creates a memory barrier "when supported by the CPU".  Another option is the  [MemoryBarrier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro.  But in most cases if you need to worry about memory caching you also need to worry about thread safety, requiring a critical section or similar.