# How to make a static member variable have different values in different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to have a member variable shared inside a thread ,but not shared among threads .

It behaves like a static member but it's only "global" in one thread ,it's a thread local variable .

I can think of two solutions :

First ,create a local variable in each thread ,then pass this variable as an argument to every method that uses it .(which result in coupling)

Or ,define a struct named MyStruct which contains a thread local variable and a thread ID ,then make all these MyStructs a vector ,use this vector as a static member variable .

Every time using this member variable , get thread ID first ,then find the MyStruct which has the same thread ID , if not found ,push back a new MyStruct .Erase this Mystruct before thread ends .(which is inconvenient)

Is there a simple solution ?

Comment: Completely unclear what you're actually asking for, sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Really?  He says exactly that he wants: (1) a member variable which is (2) a static member and (3) a thread local variable.  In the first two sentences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the thread\_local mean in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983875/what-does-the-thread-local-mean-in-c11)

Comment: @5gon12eder: Really this is the opposite.  This OP already knows what a thread local variable is, and asks how to do it in C++.  The other spotted a new keyword for creating thread local variables, and asks what they are.

Comment: @BenVoigt True, but I think that the answers to the other question (especially those with code) should give the OP enough information to solve the problem. No?

Comment: Well, none of the examples there are of member variables.  If answers there were expanded, I think it could answer this one too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ supports thread local variables since C++11, using the `thread_local` keyword.

It can be used on `static` member variables.

Using the language facility designed for this is much simpler than trying to create your own.  There are quite a few little details concerning initialization order and reentrancy, and then eventual destruction, that would be hard to get right without the compiler's help.

Comment: Thank you , this is exactly what I need .