# thread_local vs local variable in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, local-variables, thread-local

Can someone clearly and simply explain what is the difference between i and j variables?

```
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void f(int n)
{
    thread_local int i = n;
    int j = n;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(f, 1);
    thread t2(f, 2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in your case seems there's no difference

Comment: This question has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983875/what-does-the-thread-local-mean-in-c11

Comment: I didn't fined anything about comparison of these two in C++! I need to know where I should use thread_local and where I should only use local variable in function which passes to a thread.

Comment: To see the difference, add `std::cout << i++ << " " << j++ << std::endl;` into your `f` function and run a (single) thread as follows: `thread t([]{ f(1); f(1); f(1); });`. Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZbWGoWOiEDsXkUCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thread_local` implies `static` when `static` is omitted.

A local `static` variable preserves its value when a given function is called multiple times. You may read about `static` variable elsewhere.

Now, I assume you do know what `static` variable is - the important things are just:

- static variables have **local scope**
- (but) static variables have **global existence**

The second point makes a static variable's memory accessible to other functions by C++ references and pointers - it proves that the static variable has just one copy - across **all threads** of the process. You need to know what threads are and how to create/program threads.

Now, to the question. You know that **Global** variables have global scope and global accessibility, but when you run two or more instances of your program, both/all of them would have a SEPARATE copy of that global variable. That means each **process** would have a separate copy of that global variable.

So, what if you wanted to have a SEPARATE copy of `static` variable per thread? You use `thread_local`. Each thread will have a separate copy of that static variable.

Interestingly, you can apply `thread_local`  to global variables also - thence each thread will receive a separate copy of those global variables also!

```
// Globals
int counter;
thread_local int this_thread_counter; // Each thread will have separate copy
```

Now, think how `strtok` would work - think about the (concurrent) calls to `strtok` !