# boost::asio and boost::thread_group where each thread has it's own libpqxx connection

Tags: boost-asio, boost-thread, libpqxx

I'm trying to combine boost::Asio, boost::thread_group where each thread has its own libpqxx(Prostgres) connection to the database. I seem unable to find any examples of asio/thread_group where the thread the task runs on has connection specific information. Asio seems to be specialized on the task containing all the information required to run it. Am I looking at the wrong combination to solve my specific problem?

I have a lot of requests coming in to my program, each of these requests require SQL commands to be run agains the DB ( timescaledb in my case ). These requests must be run on a limited number of connections agains the DB ( normally 8 in total).

My plan was to set up a thread_group of 8 threads each with it's own connection to the DB, and each thread connected to the asio::run. So that I could post new queries to the asio::post, and get a callback via signal2 when the result comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Asio "hide" the threads, and thanks to assio::strands you can avoid more or less the concurrency. In very short you only throw task to asio, as a thread is available your task is submitted, but asio has a learning curve, as concurrency ...

As you describe your problem [thread local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983875/what-does-the-thread-local-mean-in-c11) is the answer.